# Unbiased estimator for member of random sample

Tags: statistics

Hi I am having difficulty starting this question. Any help you can provide me towards working to an answer will be much appreciated!

Question:

Let $Y_{1} ... , Y_{n}$ be a random sample with n > 1.

Show that ${\tilde{\theta}} \equiv I_{(-\infty,0]}(Y_1)$ is an unbiased estimator for $\theta \equiv P(Y_1 \lt 0)$. Compute $Var(\tilde\theta)$.

My approach (so far):

Am I right to proceed in the direction that showing E(${\tilde{\theta}} - {\theta}) = 0$ implies unbiasedness? Also for the the calculation of variance, I initially thought this could be done by working out the density for the $Y_{(1)}$ but then the question refers to $Y_1$ instead. Can you show me how should I proceed please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An indicator function takes only values 0 and 1.
(I assume you mean $Y_i$ inside that notation.)
So, what is the probability that $\tilde \theta$ is 1
and what is the probability it is 0.

In general, suppose $T$ is a random variable with
$P\{T = 1\} = p$ and $P\{T = 0\} = 1 - p.$ Then $\mu = E(T) = 0(1-p) + 1(p) = p.$
Also, why does $E(T^2) = E(T)?$ Then $V(T) = E(T^2) - \mu^2.$

You should be able to put that information together to
find the mean and variance of $\tilde \theta.$

As for the rest: (a) If by $Y_{(1)}$, you mean the first
order statistic, just from what you've said in your question,
I don't think you need to go there. (b) $E(\tilde \theta - \theta) = 0$ or, equivalently, $E(\tilde \theta) = \theta,$ certainly gets you unbiasedness.

Comment: Hi Bruce, I appreciate your help with this. I will work up a set of solutions and post it up here for review. Thanks again